# How to configure fetchmail to send messages from remote smtp server to Gmail?

Tags: smtp, email

I've been trying to setup email forwarding through fetchmail from remote smtp server to Gmail account, although messages are constantly coming to my local address and accessible via "mail" command. SMTP connection works perfectly, but emails do not go anywhere.

System: debian, fetchmail
Config: poll smtp.server protocol imap username “user” password “pass” smtpname “user@gmail.com” ssl

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the manual, it's recommend's to use  `--smtphost <server>`

source: `man fetchmail`

Did not test it but I guess it should look like something like the below:

> poll imap.domain.com with protocol IMAP
>   user 'username' password 'password' smtpname 'username@gmail.com' smtphost 'smtp.gmail.com'

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but server replies that STARTTLS should have been issued...

Comment: What if you download and install the certificate? Then specify the following as a new line: "options ssl sslcertpath /etc/ssl/certs"

Comment: @Mark It does not help.